# Salesforce APEX trigger - update parent with historical values from child

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code, apex

A small question regarding a salesforce trigger.

I have 2 objects: Parent & Child (master-detail relationship in salesforce).

Both objects are very simple:

The child record has just one value and a flag to indicate if the record is active or not.
The parent record has just two fields: "Current value of child" and "Previous value of child".

**The problem is the following:**

 I would like to write a trigger so:

-Every time a child record is flagged as not-active, to update the Parent.PreviousValue with the value of this record.

-Every time a child record is flagged as active, to update the Parent.CurrentValue with the value of this record.

Would you have any ideas regarding the trigger's logic I need to follow? For the moment I can't figure out how to start..

Comment: I think you need to alway update two fields whether or not active or inactive. Let the `PreviousValue = CurrentValue` and set the `CurrentValue = Active Count`.